# busqueda de datos según letra o palabra inicial

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Estoy realizando un programa en JS, usando AJAX y JSON, y en mi index.html, tengo dos inputs que al introducir información pues me busque y encuentre dichos datos que he colocado, hasta aquí, todo bien, mi programa funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, me gustaría saber alguna forma, de que por ejemplo, si meto en mi input de nombre, una A, pues me salgan todos los resultados que comiencen por dicha letra, o si por ejemplo, pongo el nombre Eduar, pues me busque la coincidencia según los datos que tengo guardados en mi json y me salga el resultado de Eduardo. Adjunto a continuación, mi javascript y mi html, si necesitais algo mas de mi codigo, pedminilo y adjunto lo que falte o se necesite.

```js
//MOSTRAR TODO LOS POKEMON
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.getElementById("boton-json").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                procesarRespuestaJSON1(this.responseText);
            } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                console.error('Error al hacer la petición: ' + this.status);
            }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', 'data/pokedex.json', true);
        xhr.send();
    });
    //BOTON MOSTRAR
    document.getElementById("boton-mostrar").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Pulsaste el botón mostrar.")
        let idPokemon = document.getElementById("identificador").value;
        let nombrePokemon = document.getElementById("pokemon").value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                procesarRespuestaJSON2(this.responseText, idPokemon, nombrePokemon);
            } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                console.error('Error al hacer la petición: ' + this.status);
            }
        }

        xhr.open('GET', 'data/pokedex.json', true);
        xhr.send();
    });
});

//MOSTRAR TODOS LOS POKEMON
function procesarRespuestaJSON1(respuesta) {
    let objetoJSON = JSON.parse(respuesta);
    let tabla = document.createElement('table');
    tabla.innerHTML = "<thead class='border border-white'><tr class='border border-white'><th class='border border-white'>ID</th><th class='border border-white'>Nombre</th><th class='border border-white'>Tipos</th><th class='border border-white'>Opciones</th></tr></thead>";

    for (var i = 0; i < objetoJSON.length; i++) {
        var fila = tabla.insertRow()
        fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
        fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
        fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = "<input type='submit' id='btn-seleccionar' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary'>";
    }

    document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = tabla.outerHTML;
}

//MOSTRAR SEGÚN EL ID O NOMBRE DEL POKEMON
function procesarRespuestaJSON2(respuesta, idPokemon, nombrePokemon) {
    let objetoJSON = JSON.parse(respuesta);
    let tabla = document.createElement('table');
    tabla.innerHTML = "<thead class='border border-white'><tr class='border border-white'><th class='border border-white'>ID</th><th class='border border-white'>Nombre</th><th class='border border-white'>Tipos</th><th class='border border-white'>Opciones</th></tr></thead>";

    for (var i = 0; i < objetoJSON.length; i++) {

        if((idPokemon=='')&&(objetoJSON[i].name.english == nombrePokemon))
        {
            var fila = tabla.insertRow()
            fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
            fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
            fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = "<input type='submit' id='btn-seleccionar' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary'>";
        }

        else if((objetoJSON[i].id <= idPokemon)&&(nombrePokemon == ''))
        {
            var fila = tabla.insertRow()
            fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
            fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
            fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = "<input type='submit' id='btn-seleccionar' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary'>";
        }

        else if((idPokemon='')&&(nombrePokemon=''))
        {
            if(objetoJSON[i].name.english == nombrePokemon)
            {
                var fila = tabla.insertRow()
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = "<input type='submit' id='btn-seleccionar' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary'>";
            }
         
        }
    
    }
    document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = tabla.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>POKEDEX - PRÁCTICA 3</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="styles/img/icono-pagina.png" type="image/ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="portada" class="my-row ">
        <div class="container fluid padding-portada">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <img src="styles/img/logopokemon.png" class="img-fluid aumento">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <script>
                        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                            let myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
                            myAudio.onplaying = function () {
                                isPlaying = true;
                            };
                            myAudio.onpause = function () {
                                isPlaying = false;
                            };
                        });
                        let isPlaying = false;

                        function togglePlay() {
                            if (isPlaying) {
                                myAudio.pause()
                            } else {
                                myAudio.play();
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <audio id="myAudio" src="./styles/music/musica.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

                    <a class="btn" role="button" onClick="togglePlay()">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35" height="35" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-play-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM6.79 5.093A.5.5 0 0 0 6 5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 0 .79.407l3.5-2.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.814l-3.5-2.5z" />
                        </svg></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
        <div class="container fluid padding-interfaz">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path
                            d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                            fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                    <label for="numero" class="texto">Introduce el ID:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="identificador" name="identificador" placeholder="ID del Pokemon" min="1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path
                            d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                            fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                    <label for="nombre" class="texto">Introduce el nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pokemon" name="pokemon" placeholder="Nombre del Pokemon">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <button id="boton-json">Cargar JSON</button>
                    <button id="boton-mostrar">Mostrar seleccionados</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
        <div class="container fluid">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <button onClick="window.location.reload();" class="mt-4">Refresh Page</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="zona-pokemon" class="my-row mt-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="contenedor" class="tabla">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```